# Angular Material: Setting default option from radio button group

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-material

I've been playing around with Angular Material. I think its great, but I can't figure out how to set a default value for a radio button list. I've tried to set the value and the text as well as Selected with no luck.

```
$scope.rdButton.value = 'Yes';
$scope.rdButton.text = 'Yes';
```

With `rdButton` being the name of the `ng-model` group. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rdButton` is the `ng-model`, just set `$scope.rdButton = 'Yes';` to set radio having value `Yes` as the default.

Comment: It always annoys me when these super simple ones get the better of me. This worked like a charm. Thanks for the assist TJ & akazemis. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

just mention the ng-model of which elemnt u wants to select  default

**JS**

```
 $scope.price_options = [{
        price: 10
    }, {
        price: 7
    }];
    $scope.selected_price_option = $scope.price_options[1];
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="price_option in price_options">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected_price_option" ng-value="price_option" name="quantity" />{{price_option.price}}</label>
        </div>
        {{selected_price_option}}
    </div>
```

for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/8XRnXb49cbXZpHhxBLW2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this in the HTML :

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="rdButton" value="Yes">
Yes
</input>
<input type="radio" ng-model="rdButton" value="No">
No
</input>
```

You just need to do this in the controller :

```
$scope.rdButton= 'Yes';
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks.